# How to prevent fs from unmounting?

Tags: filesystems, mount, osx, unmounting

I'm trying to back up a disk that has been acting very strangely lately, but my back-up attempts fail after a few minutes, because the disk's file system (at `/dev/disk4`) "spontaneously" unmounts.  (I doubt this unmounting is literally "spontaneous", but to my ignorance it looks that way.)

I would like to ***"lock"*** the mount, so that no other process can unmount it (other than something like `umount /dev/disk4` *issued by me*). Is there a way to achieve such a lock?

(The flavor of Unix I'm dealing with happens to be OS X, but I am interested in, say Linux-specific solutions too, since they may provide useful keyword for further Googling. Also solutions for any other BSD-ish flavor of Unix would be welcome.)

(It goes without saying that I am interested only in locking schemes that do not prevent me from backing up the disk!)

If there is no way to "lock the mount"
 or how can I determine why the unmounting is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the mount is busy it shouldn't be able to unmount*.

An easy way to make a mount busy is to have at least one process with its `CWD` (**C**urrent **W**orking **D**irectory) under the mount point.

---

*Lazy unmounts will still return but it shouldn't actually unmount until the filesystem is no longer busy.