# is it possible mount automatically if from some reason mount folder isn't mounted

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, fstab, automounting

we create the following mount point and nfsshare folder as share folder on all our linux client machines ( total 1872 machines - redhat 7.2 )

```
master1:/nfs             41932800 6563840  35368960  16% /nfsshare
```

I just thinking about if from some reason by mistake someone of our users decided by mistake to perform umount to /nfsshare

in that case it will cause real problem to the application

so is it possible mount automatically if from some reason mount folder isn't mounted ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent fs unmounting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43546/how-to-prevent-fs-unmounting)

Comment: I dont understand the resoling on this post - how to prevent umount!

Comment: which part you didn't understand? please [edit] your question and tell us

Comment: please explain - what need to set in order to mount auto after folder is unmounted?

Comment: Re: "_`I just thinking about if from some reason by mistake someone of our users decided by mistake to perform umount to /nfsshare`_" --- the flagged post is showing you how to prevent it from unmounting already. to mount it automatically first you need to [find-out if a mount point is unmounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38870/72456) then write script to mount it again --- vv Yes, possible

Comment: but I am asking about how to mount again auto after some time , - is it possible - tes/no?

Comment: Unless your users have root privileges, they should not be able to unmount a NFS filesystem mounted as root - unless you've specifically permitted that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using RHEL 7.x, you could use a systemd `.automount` unit. Just make an entry like this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
master1:/nfs /nfsshare nfs defaults,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

- mount option `noauto` disables classic-style mounting at boot time
- mount option `x-systemd.automount` causes `systemd-fstab-generator` to create an `.automount` unit in addition to a regular `.mount` unit. (Note: parallelizable `.mount` units are the way `systemd` handles filesystem mounts specified in `/etc/fstab`, instead of a traditional single-threaded `mount -a`.)

Make sure the mount-point directory `/nfsshare` exists; in theory `systemd` should automatically create it if it does not exist, but [right now there is a bug affecting the auto-creation of mount points.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1585411)

This will auto-mount the specified filesystem *on demand*: whenever an user process touches `/nfsshare`, the NFS filesystem will be automatically and transparently mounted if it isn't already mounted.

Comment: can you see please my thread on - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518226/automount-nfs-on-redhat-7-2-not-works

Answer (score 0):

This could be performed by a script or command line launched by a crontab.
The command would be like :

```
mount | grep /nfsshare || [your mount command]
```

details :

- `mount | grep /nfsshare` : search your mount point in the list of active mounts
- the double pipe `||` is a Bash construct for "*do this if the preceding command returns a non-success*"
- ... then actually `mount` your NFS share