# Automount nfs on redhat 7.2 not works

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, nfs, services

I have the following nfd share folder on my linux client ( redhat 7.2 )

```
master1:/nfs             41932800 6601728  35331072  16% /nfsshare
```

we decided to use the service auto fs in case this share folder is unmounted

we created the following service ( according to link - https://michlstechblog.info/blog/systemd-automount-nfs-export/ )

```
ls -ltr  auto-mnt.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 212 May 10 12:38 auto-mnt.service
```

the conf

```
 more  auto-mnt.service
[Unit]
  Description=nfs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Mount]
  What=master1:/nfs
  Where=/nfsshare
  Options=
  Type=nfs

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and

```
 systemctl start auto-mnt.service
Failed to start auto-mnt.service: Unit auto-mnt.service failed to load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status auto-mnt.service' for details.
[root@ system]# systemctl status auto-mnt.service
● auto-mnt.service - nfs mount script
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

from fstab

```
master1:/nfs  /nfsshare nfs defaults,noauto,x-systemd.automount,group,noauto,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min 0 0
```

we not understand why service complain about -

```
[/etc/systemd/system/auto-mnt.service:6] Unknown section 'Mount'. Ignoring.
auto-mnt.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.

Unknown section 'Mount'. Ignoring
```

what is wrong in service syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The systemd unit should be called “nfsshare.mount” if you are creating a mountpoint called /nfsshare. It is not a Service unit so calling it .service is nonsense, which is why you are getting that error.

Also, if you create a mount unit, it is no longer necessary (and will likely cause problems) to have an entry in /etc/fstab.

Comment: I change the service name to nfsshare.mount under /etc/systemd/system and the line in fstab is -  master1:/nfs  /nfsshare nfs defaults,noauto,x-systemd.automount,group,noauto,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min 0 0   , but still not get the mount back after 1 min , can you please advice what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean “still not get the mount back”. Did you activate the mount unit after doing a daemon-reload?

Comment: An entry in `/etc/fstab` will cause a corresponding `.mount` unit file be auto-generated at boot time by `systemd-fstab-generator`. Your custom `.mount` unit will override that. Pick either an `fstab` entry or a hand-written `nfsshare.mount` unit; don't attempt to use both together. If you need to customize a generated mount unit, you can use `systemctl edit nfsshare.mount` to extend it with a drop-in file. *Automount* units don't (re)mount the filesystem until something attempts to use that filesystem; the idle-timeout option makes systemd *unmount* the automounted filesystem if not needed.

Comment: +1 , ok I will reconfigure the service I and I will test it

Comment: now I have another issue , after the service is up and mount point mounted  , then I umount the mountpoint , but service isnt active again the mount point , I will post a new question

Comment: see my new update - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518492/auto-mount-by-service-service-not-mount-the-folder-automatically

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [jsbillings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3976/jsbillings)'s answer that your file should have `.mount` extention, you should consider to name your file after mount destination, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345518/552756) is more detail.

For example if your file is like this

```
...
Where=/mnt/data
...
```

file name need to be `mnt-data.mount`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).