# auto mount by service + service not mount the folder automatically

Tags: linux, rhel, systemd, services, systemctl

we create the following service on redhat version 7.2

```
more nfsshare.mount
[Unit]
  Description=nfs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Mount]

  What=master1:/nfs
  Where=/nfsshare
  Options=noauto,user,rw,group
  Type=nfs
  TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after restart the service the mount point is mounted as should be

```
master1:/nfs             41932800 6559744  35373056  16% /nfsshare
```

now we umount the /nfsshare folder

```
umount /nfsshare
```

now we expecting  /nfsshare folder will be mounted again 
and service will automatically mout the folder

but nothing is happens and folder not mounted

where I am wrong here?

I also try

```
 more nfsshare.automount
[Unit]
  Description=nfs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Automount]
  What=master1:/nfs
  Where=/nfsshare
  Options=noauto,user,rw,group
  Type=nfs
  TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but this service even not mount the folder after restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct setup is for unit `nfsshare.mount` to contain:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount nfsshare
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=master1:/nfs
Where=/nfsshare
Options=rw,group
Type=nfs
```

And for unit `nfsshare.automount` to contain:

```
[Unit]
Description=Automount nfsshare
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Automount]
Where=/nfsshare
TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And you typically want to enable the `.automount` unit only:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable nfsshare.automount
```

With this setup, right after you boot (assuming no running daemons have accessed the NFS share), then the share will *not* be mounted. But once it is accessed (with e.g. `ls /nfsshare`) then it will be mounted on demand. It will stay mounted for 10s and then unmounted, but mounted once again after accessed another time.

The two units `.mount` and `.automount` work together to trigger this behavior. The `.automount` unit simply needs to know the mount point directory where to set up an automount. Once that directory is accessed, then it will trigger a request for the `.mount` unit with the same name (for the same path) and will wait until that unit is up before proceeding.

See the [man page for automount units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) for more details.

---

What else have I changed from your setup?

For networking dependencies, you should use `network-online.target`, not `.service` which doesn't exist. I'm also using `Wants=`, which is the recommended directive for this case (see [this wiki page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) for a deeper discussion on the network targets.)

I removed `noauto` and `user` from your mount options, as those only really make sense in `/etc/fstab`. I'd also argue you don't really want to have `user` in there, just have it automounted instead of allowing unprivileged users to mount it calling the `mount` util, automounting is better.

The directives taken on which unit are distinct (except for `Where=` that is taken by both), so I only kept the valid ones there.

I removed the `[Install]` section of the `.mount` unit, since you don't need to enable it. You only need to enable the `.automount` unit so it's brought up at boot, then that unit will be responsible for bringing up (and down) the mount unit whenever needed (depending on the target directory being accessed.)

---

Note that you can also configure all this (including the automount) in `/etc/fstab`. In fact, systemd typically recommends using `/etc/fstab` for configuration rather than creating mount units.

For automounting, all you need to do is add a `x-systemd.automount` pseudo-option to the list of mount options of your `/etc/fstab` entry for this filesystem. (You typically want to include `noauto` as well in that case.)

See [this section of the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Automount_with_systemd) for more details. (None of that is really specific to Arch Linux, it should all work exactly the same on RHEL 7.)