# Is there a way to tell if tee is writing to a mounted filesystem?

Tags: mount, lsof

I backup my hard drive through `sudo zfs send snapshot | sudo tee /my-mount-point/my-snapshot.zfs > /dev/null`, and I want to make sure that I don't accidentally unmount (and turn off) /my-mount-point.

Now, had I `cd` into there, it wouldn't be a problem, as I would get `umount: /my-mount-point: target is busy.`. But with `tee`, it doesn't do that.

Moreover, when I try running `lsof | grep "my-mount-point"`, I get nothing. If I cd into my-mount-point, lsof will show it. Otherwise, nothing.

Is there a way to get if *something*'s writing to a file under `my-mount-point`?

Comment: As a side note, your command line is strange. Since you don't output the backup to stdout, you don't need `tee`, `sudo zfs send snapshot > /my-mount-point/my-snapshot.zfs` is enough, isn't it?

Comment: @Amessihel not if /my-mount-pointt isn't user writable

Comment: Even with the `sudo` call, you're sure?

Answer (score 0):

Why not CD-ing into that directory before backing up your HD?

```
cd /my-mount-point/ &&
(sudo zfs send snapshot | 
 sudo tee my-snapshot.zfs > /dev/null) && cd
```

Sounds to be the easiest way to get [a CWD under your mount point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43547/138686).